# Chamar função javascript com parâmetro nulo

Tags: javascript, parâmetros, funções, argumento

A função `verificaCampoVazios` possui dois parâmetros (`fs` e `campos`).

```
verificaCamposVazios = function (fs, campos)
{
 console.log(campos[0]);
}
```

Exemplo de como é chamada função:

```
verificaCamposVazios(fsInformacaoCandidatoDados, ArrayCamposNaoObrigatorios);
```

Como faço para chamar a função sem passar o parâmetro `campos`?

Eu chamei a função assim:

```
verificaCamposVazios(fsInformacaoCandidatoDados);
```

E a função não foi executada, mas não apresentou erro no `console.log` do `Chrome`.

Gostaria de entender como chamo a função sem passar um argumento.

Comment: Já tentou `verificaCamposVazios(fsInformacaoCandidatoDados, null);`?

Comment: vou tentar agora

Comment: Não há problema em chamar a função com argumentos a menos... -> https://jsfiddle.net/7dnc5kh0/ podes criar um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema?

Comment: Achei que quando o argumento não era passado, o argumento da function já era null

Comment: com null dá erro também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `null` como argumento:

```
verificaCamposVazios(fsInformacaoCandidatoDados, null);
```

Mas normalmente a falta deste não deveria ser problema nenhum, pois o valor omitido será nulo de qualquer maneira.

No caso específico da pergunta, pode ser uma característica da própria função reagir diferentemente com base no número de parâmetros, com base na função `arguments.length`.

Por exemplo, a função chamada pode ter algo assim implementado:

```
if( arguments.length < 2 ) {
   ... retorna sem fazer nada ...
```

o que seria uma especificidade da função em si, e não do `null` propriamente dito.

Comment: Na função existe uma condição que lê o parâmetro e faz uma comparação. Será que o erro pode ser esse? Como não tem parâmetro, a função fica louca.

Comment: Não creio que seja isso, pq o null seria o mesmo (a nao ser que a comparação seja com undefined, como o Pedro comentou). Não tem como vc jogar a função no Codepen, JSFiddle, ou algum lugar do tipo? Aí ficaria mais fácil de analisarmos.

Comment: olhe a edição que fiz na pergunta. Agora você vai entender que a função tenta ler algo que não existe.

Comment: Vc está usando índice. Aí vai dar problema chamando com nulo de qualquer jeito, não é o que vc perguntou inicialmente. O problema independe de passar o null como parametro ou não. Seria o caso de aplicar um valor default para o caso de vir vazio.

Comment: Você está correto, e você já previu isso na sua resposta

Comment: @durtto tanto a resposta do Pedro quanto a minha tem informações importantes, é que sem ver a função, nos baseamos em teorias. dependendo do que for fazer, o nulo é importante, dependendo do caso pode ser melhor o undefined; Nas próximas questoes procure por o máximo de detalhes, que ai a gente consegue te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Sim. Infelizmente o erro estava justamente onde eu não mostrei. Isso acontece, e percebi que sua resposta tratou justamente desse trecho que não mostrei. Fico muito grato. Me ajudou muito pois meu trabalho estava parado. Obrigado pela humildade de vocês dois e atenção.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode chamar uma função com parâmetros ausentes sem nenhum problema, inclusive é uma prática (até onde sei) para parâmetros opcionais, a única coisa que você deve fazer para evitar erros, é verificar se o parâmetro não é `undefined` dentro da sua função.

```
verificaCamposVazios = function (fs, campos)
{
    if (campos !== undefined) {
        console.log(campos[0]);
    }    
}
```

Para fazer a chamada da função, não será necessário passar o segundo parâmetro nem passá-lo como `null`.

```
verificaCamposVazios(fsInformacaoCandidatoDados);
```

Comment: Na função existe uma condição que lê o parâmetro e faz uma comparação. Será que o erro pode ser esse? Como não tem parâmetro, a função fica louca.

Comment: Acredito que sim, esse parâmetro estrá `undefined`, tenta fazer a verificação do valor antes de usar o parâmetro.

Comment: Você está certo. Fiz assim. if (fs == null  || campos == null)
{
return -1
}

Comment: Note que `null` é diferente de `undefined`. Se você não passar nada no segundo parâmetro será `undefined` e não `null`

Comment: Obrigado Pedro pela ajuda.